# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table cliente
(
id_cli varchar (11) not null,
nom_cli varchar (30) not null,
ape_cli varchar (30) not null,
dir_cli varchar (100) not null,
dep_cli varchar (20) not null,
mes_cum_cli varchar (10) not null,
primary key (id_cli)
);
create table articulo
(
id_art int auto_increment not null,
tit_art varchar (100) not null,
aut_art varchar (100) not null,
edi_art varchar (300) not null,
prec_art decimal not null,
primary key (id_art)
)auto_increment = 1;
create table pedido
(
id_ped int primary key auto_increment not null,
id_cli_ped varchar (11) not null,
fec_ped date not null,
val_ped decimal not null,
foreign key (id_cli_ped) references cliente (id_cli)
) auto_increment=1;
```

Insertando valores.

```
insert into cliente
values
('63502718','Maritza','Rojas','Calle 34 N° 14-45','Santander','Abril'),
('13890234','Roger','Ariza','Cra 30 N° 13-45','Antioquia','Junio'),
('77191956','Juan Carlos ','Arenas','Diagonal 23 N° 12-34 apt 101','Valle','Marzo'),
('1098765789','Catalina ','Zapata','Av. EL libertador N° 30-14','Cauca','Marzo');

insert into articulo
values
(1,'Redes cisco','Ernesto Arigasello','Alfaomega-Rama','60000'),
(null,'Facebook y Twitter para adultos','Veloso Claudio','Alfaomega','52000'),
(null,'Creacion de un portal con php y mysql','Jacob Pavón Puertas','Alfaomega-Rama','40000'),
(null,'Administración de sistemas operativos','Julio Gomez López','Alfaomega-Rama','55000');

insert into pedido
values
(1,'63502718','2012-02-25','120000'),
(null,'77191956','2012-04-30','55000'),
(null,'30502718','2011-12-10','260000'),
(null,'1098765789','2012-02-25','1800000');

0   18  10:31:19    insert into pedido
 values
 (1,'63502718','2012-02-25','120000'),
 (null,'77191956','2012-04-30','55000'),
 (null,'30502718','2011-12-10','260000'),
 (null,'1098765789','2012-02-25','1800000');
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laboratoriosql`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `pedido_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cli_ped`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`id_cli`)) 0.093 sec

Comment: El error se da por este valor: `30502718` en la tabla `pedidos` el mismo trata de ser una referencia como llave foránea a la tabla `clientes` pero en dicha tabla ese valor no existe por tanto no lo puedes usar así nadamás

Answer (score 1):

El error se da por este valor:

```
30502718
```

En la tabla **`pedidos`** el mismo trata de ser una referencia como llave foránea a un registro en la tabla **`clientes`** pero en dicha tabla ese valor no existe.

Recuerda que tus *FK* son un valor enlazado a una *PK* (**en este caso**) en otra tabla, por tanto debes asegurarte que ese valor exista en el origen (*tu tabla `clientes`*) antes de intentar usarlo.

Por otro lado un tanto ajeno a la pregunta pero igual lo menciono, si vas iniciar tu secuencia para el [`AUTO INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) desde 1 entonces no hace falta lo especifiques